# Fetch Entity Reference by Non-Primary Key Column

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities, "User" and "Record", where the Record references a User but not by the User's primary key, but rather another column that is also unique, namely the username:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

     @Id
     private Long id;

     @NaturalId
     private String username;

     ...
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Record {

     @Id
     private Long id;

     @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
     @JoinColumn(name = "username", referencedColumnName = "username")
     private User user;

     ...
}
```

When creating a new Record, using Hibernate's getReferenceById does not work:

```
@Transactional
public Record createRecord(Long userId) {
     Record record = new Record()
     record.setUser(userRepository.getReferenceById(userId));

     return recordRepository.save(record);
}
```

The not-null constraint on the username column of the Record table is violated since the username is not loaded. This does make sense since the getReferenceById method of the JpaRepository interface just returns a proxy and would not return the username. Using the findById method solves this problem, but executes an additional query that I would like to avoid:

```
@Transactional
public Record createRecord(Long userId) {
     Record record = new Record()
     record.setUser(userRepository.findById(userId).orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);

     return recordRepository.save(record);
}
```

Is it possible to fetch an entity reference via a "natural ID" or another unique column?

Additional things to note:

1. The database schema is managed by Flyway, even in the test context.
2. Yes, I could just use the numeric ID as the foreign key reference, but I would like to instead use the username.
3. I know that I could also forgo using the @ManyToOne relationship all together and just use the username in the record class, but I am more interested in the general possibility of leveraging such unique non-primary key columns with Hibernate/Spring Data JPA to the same extent that IDs can be used.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to fetch an entity reference via a "natural ID" or another unique column?

You can't create a proxy based on a non-primary key, so no, it's not possible to persist a `Record` without querying the `User` first.

One thing you could do, is to map the column twice and set the basic FK also.

```
@Entity
public class Record {

     @Id
     private Long id;

     @Column(name = "username", nullable = false)
     private String username;

     @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
     @JoinColumn(name = "username", referencedColumnName = "username", insertable = false, updatable = false)
     private User user;

     ...
}
```